# Why is my Android Studio 3.5 missing Settings > Editor > Code Style?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I want to change settings such as number of spaces in a tab and Java import order, which is supposed to be under Settings > Editor > Code Style, but that simply doesn't exist for me anymore. I suspect it's due to me accidentally deleting some ~/.Intellij directory thinking I didn't need it anymore, but I still have ~/.AndroidStudioPreview3.5/config/codestyles/ which I thought is what I needed... maybe there's some preference to point to that directory instead of the old Intellij one I deleted?

If you're curious about what settings I *do* have, this is what I see under Editor: General, Font, Color Scheme, Inspections, File and Code Templates, File Encodings, Live Templates, File Types, Layout Editor, Copyright, Emmet, Images, Intentions, Language Injections, Spelling, and TODO. But no Code Style! What gives?

Comment: Any third-party plug-ins installed? Any exceptions in the [logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: No plugins installed. Don't see any exceptions in the logs. Interestingly, clicking "Compress Logs and Show in Files" as the link says didn't actually take me to the logs, it took me to /tmp. I had to manually figure out that the logs are actually in ~/.AndroidStudioPreview3.5/system/log. I wonder if that's related to the issue I'm facing - perhaps Android Studio doesn't know where my system and config directories are? But changing idea.properties didn't seem to help. 
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview3.5/config
idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudioPreview3.5/system

Comment: Try reinstalling, then delete `~/.AndroidStudioPreview3.5` to start with the defaults.